# ¿Es correcta la fórmula "estimados todos"?

Tags: pronombres, adjetivos, sustantivos, cortesía, correspondencia

Últimamente veo mucho usar la fórmula

> Estimados todos:

en los encabezados de algunas cartas. ¿Es correcta dicha fórmula? En principio, lo sería si "todos" se usara como sustantivo, pero los significados de "[todo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZxVCoJq)" como sustantivo son:

> 14. m. Cosa íntegra, conjunto indivisible o inseparable de los elementos que componen algo. *Se fijan ustedes en las partes sin atender al todo.*
> 15. m. En el juego del hombre y otros de naipes, condición en que se paga más a quien hace todas las bazas.
> 16. m. En las charadas, voz que contiene en sí todas las sílabas que se han enunciado.

El uso que se da en la carta sería de pronombre:

> 9. pron. indef. m. pl. todas las personas. U. sin referencia a un sintagma mencionado o sobrentendido. *La limpieza de la ciudad nos concierne a todos.*

Luego en la carta tenemos un adjetivo precediendo a un pronombre. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: Is the story of the lovers of Teruel relevant here? "los amantes de Teruel: tonta ella, tonto él".  This seems to me to have pronouns qualified by adjectives.

Comment: Te refieres al uso de "todo"/"todos"?

Comment: @Theia bueno, es simplemente que la fórmula me suena rara y no sé si es por falta de costumbre o si es que es incorrecta por algún motivo.

Comment: ¿En qué tipo de cartas has visto eso? Espero que no sean cosas serias porque eso de "estimados todos" puede valer en tono irónico y de broma pero dudo que sea correcto.

Comment: @blonfu todo lo serio que puede ser un departamento de recursos humanos de una mediana empresa.

Comment: Una de las funciones del pronombre es reemplazar al sustantivo (nombre), de ahí su etimología. No veo qué hay de malo, aunque pueda ser menos formal. _Esa blanca es más bonita_: blanca (adj.) califica a esa (pron.)

Answer (score 6):

*Estimados todos* es una traducción literal del inglés *Dear All*.

Su uso en el castellano no es correcto, ya que después del saludo hay que especificar a quién te estás refiriendo -un sustantivo- y el término *todos* es un pronombre, el uso correcto es:

- Queridos amigos
- Estimados conciudadanos
- Estimados (sustantivo)

Comment: De acuerdo con iDebug. En español se puede utilizar el adjetivo "estimados" sustantivado, o sea, en reemplazo del sustantivo, pero no en inglés, donde "dear" puede usarse solo únicamente cuando el referente es singular y en la forma oral: *Hello, dear.*

Comment: @Gustavson no entendí lo de _dear_ en singular. ¿qué tal _dear friends_ //  _Hello dear friends_? ¿Podrías explicar un poco?.

Comment: Lo que quise decir es que en inglés "dear" puede usarse solo, o sea sin sustantivo que lo acompañe, solo cuando se refiere al singular. En cambio, en español se pueden usar solas tanto la forma singular (*estimado/a*) como la forma plural (*estimados/estimadas*).

Comment: Perhaps we are going a bit off topic here but _dears_ is used, not that commonly in the phrase _my dears_.

Answer (score 5):

Por recuperar esta pregunta que se me había quedado un poco atrás, comentar que envié [un tuit](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/885066565611384832) en su día a la RAE preguntando esta cuestión, y me respondieron [lo siguiente](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/885121086274273280):

> Generalmente se emplea un encabezamiento más específico, pero el que propone no es incorrecto.

No me especificaron el motivo exacto, y sé que más de uno tiene ciertos reparos con los tuits de la RAE cuando no son demasiado concretos. Supongo que la motivación que tendrá la RAE es que se trata de un neologismo que está cobrando fuerza en los últimos años, y acabará siendo aceptado al igual que se va a aceptar ["iros"](https://twitter.com/perezreverte/status/886689800136392704) como forma popular del imperativo de "ir".

Comment: En este [artículo](http://www.eluniverso.com/vida-estilo/2016/07/03/nota/5668233/esquina-idioma) dice que es coloquial y que no debería usarse en cartas formales. No se quien es esta mujer pero me parece razonable su explicación.